# Sum values of a .txt file using .bat command

Tags: batch-file

I have this script below:

```
set "$file=futuroscielotan.txt"
set "$search=Previsto"

set $repl[2]=TOTAL       
set $repl[3]=Visa        
set $repl[4]=Mastercard  
set $repl[5]=Amex        
set $repl[6]=Sorocred    
set $repl[7]=Elo         
set $repl[8]=Diners      
set $repl[9]=Agiplan     
set $repl[10]=Banescard   
set $repl[11]=Cabal       
set $repl[12]=Credsystem  
set $repl[13]=Hipercard   
set $repl[14]=Credz       
set $repl[15]=Hiper       

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set $count=1

(for /f "delims=" %%a in (%$file%) do (
   call:replace "%%a" !$count!
   set/a $count+=1
   )
)> "Futuros Cielo Tan.txt"
echo. >> "Futuros Cielo Tan.txt"
echo ---  FUTUROS CIELO TAN --- >> "Futuros Cielo Tan.txt"

mkdir "C:\Users\lojas\Desktop\Extratos Banco" 
move "Futuros Cielo Tan.txt" "C:\Users\lojas\Desktop\Extratos Banco\Futuros Cielo Tan.txt"

exit/b

:replace
set "$line=%~1"
set $repl=!$repl[%2]!
set "$line=!$line:%$search%=%$repl%!"
echo !$line!
if "%2"=="1" echo.
if "%2"=="2" echo.
```

The output `.txt` file of this script is that bellow:

```
01/06/2018 à 20/03/2019

TOTAL       :  R$ 22.250,74  

Visa        :  R$ 1.086,51  
Mastercard  :  R$ 492,63  
Amex        :  R$ 0,00  
Sorocred    :  R$ 20.109,98  
Elo         :  R$ 0,00  
Diners      :  R$ 0,00  
Agiplan     :  R$ 0,00  
Banescard   :  R$ 0,00  
Cabal       :  R$ 0,00  
Credsystem  :  R$ 0,00  
Hipercard   :  R$ 0,00  
Credz       :  R$ 0,00  

---  FUTUROS CIELO TAN ---
```

But i need a way to sum the values of the cards and create another line called `TOTAL VALUE OF CARDS CHECKED: xxxxxx`

It must be like below:

```
01/06/2018 à 20/03/2019

TOTAL       :  R$ 22.250,74  

Visa        :  R$ 1.086,51  
Mastercard  :  R$ 492,63  
Amex        :  R$ 0,00  
Sorocred    :  R$ 20.109,98  
Elo         :  R$ 0,00  
Diners      :  R$ 0,00  
Agiplan     :  R$ 0,00  
Banescard   :  R$ 0,00  
Cabal       :  R$ 0,00  
Credsystem  :  R$ 0,00  
Hipercard   :  R$ 0,00  
Credz       :  R$ 0,00  

TOTAL CARD VALUES CHECKED: R$ 21.689,12

---  FUTUROS CIELO TAN ---
```

How can i do it?

---

Just tried make another command only for test. Follow bellow:

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=R$ " %%a in (Futuros Cielo Tan.txt) do set /a total+=%%a
echo TOTAL CHECKED:  %total% >test.txt
```

But it isn't summing. It's always putting a `0`, like this: `TOTAL CHECKED:  0`

Comment: You were already provided with some advice earlier, when you asked the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51002283), and then deleted it! You should not have created a new question, you should have made your changes to the deleted question, including the advice given, then undeleted it. Please doublequote your variables so that the variables and values are enclosed inside those doublequotes, e.g. `Set "$repl[5]=Amex        "`! _(Set "$repl[5]=Amex<8 spaces>")_.

Comment: Just deleted because i found what was wrong, and my other doubt was different. So to avoid confusing with the people are with the same problem, just deleted that and created this solid question. _Long time no see you Compo...._

Comment: @Karen: you should be aware that users with enaugh reputation can still **see** your question - so deleting doesn't solve your problem but reduces our tolerance to help you further. SO here is my comment (Pad spaces exchanged with dots) **I am sorry to say this, but I feel programming batch and you will never get friends. Pad $repl[2..15] with spaces right to a unique length and enclose the `set "$repl[2]=TOTAL......."` command in double quotes (IIRC you were told that repeatedly)**

Comment: Guys, let me process all that and remake my script, then i tell you. Thanks for a whiele.

Comment: @Compo check my last edit!

Comment: @LotPings check my last edit!

Comment: I've now deleted the script I provided in the answer area. _Altbough I've no idea what the two lines you've added were actually added for, especially as there's no such command as `Pad` and having a variable named, `%$ repl[2] %` seems more than a little strange!_ Finally you were informed that you're supposed to attempt to code the script for the task yourself, not expect somebody else to do it for you.

Comment: @Compo _My dear friend, i wasn't rude, i'm angry like a wild hungry tiger...._ Your script worked correct i checked it, is better than my previous...but it don't summed the card values for me check....

Comment: @Karen, I've adjusted my code and undeleted it, please feel free to give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karen, given the input file, `futuroscielotan.txt`, as previously provided in your deleted question:

```
01/06/2018 à 20/03/2019
Previsto:  R$ 22.250,74  
Previsto:  R$ 1.086,51  
Previsto:  R$ 492,63  
Previsto:  R$ 0,00  
Previsto:  R$ 20.109,98  
Previsto:  R$ 0,00  
Previsto:  R$ 0,00  
Previsto:  R$ 0,00  
Previsto:  R$ 0,00  
Previsto:  R$ 0,00  
Previsto:  R$ 0,00  
Previsto:  R$ 0,00  
Previsto:  R$ 0,00
```

The script in your question could look like this, *(untested)*:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "$file=futuroscielotan.txt"
Set "$search=Previsto"
Set "$outdir=C:\Users\lojas\Desktop\Extratos Banco"
Set "$outfile=Futuros Cielo Tan.txt"

Set "$repl[2]=TOTAL       "
Set "$repl[3]=Visa        "
Set "$repl[4]=Mastercard  "
Set "$repl[5]=Amex        "
Set "$repl[6]=Sorocred    "
Set "$repl[7]=Elo         "
Set "$repl[8]=Diners      "
Set "$repl[9]=Agiplan     "
Set "$repl[10]=Banescard   "
Set "$repl[11]=Cabal       "
Set "$repl[12]=Credsystem  "
Set "$repl[13]=Hipercard   "
Set "$repl[14]=Credz       "
Set "$repl[15]=Hiper       "

If Not Exist "%$outdir%\" (MD "%$outdir%" 2>Nul || Exit /B)

Set /A $count=1,$real=$cent=0
(
    For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("%$file%") Do (
        Call :Replace "%%A" "!$count!"
        Set /A $count+=1
    )
    If Not "!$cent:~,-2!"=="" Set /A $real=$real+!$cent:~,-2!
    If Not "!$real:~,-3!"=="" Set "$real=!$real:~,-3!.!$real:~-3!"
    If Not "!$real:~,-7!"=="" Set "$real=!$real:~,-7!.!$real:~-7!"
    If Not "!$real:~,-11!"=="" Set "$real=!$real:~,-11!.!$real:~-11!"
    Set "$cent=0!$cent!"
    Echo(
    Echo TOTAL CARD VALUES CHECKED:  R$ !$real!,!$cent:~-2!
    Echo(
    Echo ---  FUTUROS CIELO TAN ---
)>"%$outdir%\%$outfile%"

Pause
Exit /B

:Replace
Set "$line=%~1"
If %~2 GEq 3 Call :Calcs !$line:*$=!
Set "$repl=!$repl[%~2]!"
Set "$line=!$line:%$search%=%$repl%!"
Echo %$line%
If %~2 Equ 1 Echo(
If %~2 Equ 2 Echo(
Exit /B

:Calcs
If %1 Gtr 0 (Set "$_r=%1"
    Set "$_r=!$_r:.=!"
    Set /A $real+=$_r)
If %2 Gtr 0 (Set /A $_c=10%2%%100
    Set /A $cent+=$_c)
Exit /B
```

Comment: Worked fine. Clean and functional...liked the part of the `calcs` it's intereseting. Thank you!

Comment: @Karen, I've made a small change to the centavos output, please update and try it again; thank you.

Comment: Just a last doubt. I changed the line `Echo TOTAL CARD VALUES CHECKED:  R$ !$real!,!$cent:~-2!` to `Echo IL TOTAL DI CARTÕES CONFERIDO:  R$ !$real!,!$cent:~-2!`, but the charachter `õ` isn't be recognized. I tried this way `^õ` also double it `õõ` but no way worked. How i do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "$file=futuroscielotan.txt"
set "$search=Previsto"
set "output=Futuros Cielo Tan.txt"

set "$repl[2]=TOTAL       "
set "$repl[3]=Visa        "
set "$repl[4]=Mastercard  "
set "$repl[5]=Amex        "
set "$repl[6]=Sorocred    "
set "$repl[7]=Elo         "
set "$repl[8]=Diners      "
set "$repl[9]=Agiplan     "
set "$repl[10]=Banescard   "
set "$repl[11]=Cabal       "
set "$repl[12]=Credsystem  "
set "$repl[13]=Hipercard   "
set "$repl[14]=Credz       "
set "$repl[15]=Hiper       "

set "$count=1"
set "total=0"

:: Empty output file.
2> "%output%" echo.

:: Process input file and sum the currency.
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%$file%") do (
    call :replace "%%A" !$count! >> "%output%"
    set /a $count+=1

    for /f "tokens=1-4" %%B in ("%%~A") do (
        if /i not "%%~B" == "total" if /i "%%~D" == "R$" (
            call :sum "%%~E"
        )
    )
)

:: Modifies total to european currency notation.
call :digits2currency "%total%"

(
    echo.
    echo TOTAL CARD VALUES CHECKED: R$ %total%
    echo.
    echo ---  FUTUROS CIELO TAN ---
) >> "%output%"

@rem mkdir "C:\Users\lojas\Desktop\Extratos Banco"
@rem move "Futuros Cielo Tan.txt" "C:\Users\lojas\Desktop\Extratos Banco\Futuros Cielo Tan.txt"

exit/b

:replace
    set "$line=%~1"
    set $repl=!$repl[%2]!
    set "$line=!$line:%$search%=%$repl%!"
    echo !$line!
    if "%2"=="1" echo.
    if "%2"=="2" echo.
exit /b

:sum
    setlocal
    set "string=%~1"
    if not defined string exit /b 0

    :: Remove separators.
    set "digits=%string:,=%"
    set "digits=%digits:.=%"

    :: Remove a leading 0 so not treated as octal notation.
    if "%digits:~0,1%" == "0" set "digits=%digits:~1%"
    if "%digits:~0,1%" == "0" set "digits=%digits:~1%"
    if not defined string set "string=0"

    endlocal & set /a "total+=%digits%"
exit /b 0

:digits2currency
    setlocal
    set "digits=%~1"

    :: Set decimal digits.
    set "subtotal=,%digits:~-2%"
    set "digits=%digits:~0,-2%"

    if defined digits goto :loop

    :: Trim 1st separator.
    set "subtotal=%subtotal:~1%"

    :: Add leading zeros.
    if "%subtotal:~0,-1%" == "" (
        set "subtotal=0,0%subtotal%"
    ) else (
        set "subtotal=0,%subtotal%"
    )

    endlocal & set "total=%subtotal%"
    exit /b

    :: Set thousandths digits.
    :loop
        set "subtotal=.%digits:~-3%%subtotal%"
        set "digits=%digits:~0,-3%"
    if defined digits goto :loop

    :: Trim 1st separator.
    set "subtotal=%subtotal:~1%"

    endlocal & set "total=%subtotal%"
exit /b 0
```

Based on 1st code and the label `:replace` is unmodified.
Commented `mkdir` and `move` lines for testing.

Used this as input which determined tokens setting in `for` loop:

```
01/06/2018 à 20/03/2019
TOTAL       :  R$ 22.250,74 
Visa        :  R$ 1.086,51  
Mastercard  :  R$ 492,63  
Amex        :  R$ 0,00  
Sorocred    :  R$ 20.109,98  
Elo         :  R$ 0,00  
Diners      :  R$ 0,00  
Agiplan     :  R$ 0,00  
Banescard   :  R$ 0,00  
Cabal       :  R$ 0,00  
Credsystem  :  R$ 0,00  
Hipercard   :  R$ 0,00  
Credz       :  R$ 0,00
```

The called label `:sum` removes leading zero, comma and
decimal point from each currency string passed. It adds
the remaining integer to the total variable with `set /a`.

The called label `:digits2currency` formats the integer
value of `total` to currency notation. If decimal only,
it will complete early with updating the formatted string,
otherwise does the thousandths. The `total` variable is
reused from integer string to currency string.

Also try this input:

```
01/06/2018 à 20/03/2019
TOTAL       :  R$ 0,00 
Visa        :  R$ 0,09  
Mastercard  :  R$ 0,00  
Amex        :  R$ 0,00  
Sorocred    :  R$ 0,00  
Elo         :  R$ 0,00  
Diners      :  R$ 0,00  
Agiplan     :  R$ 0,00  
Banescard   :  R$ 0,00  
Cabal       :  R$ 0,00  
Credsystem  :  R$ 0,00  
Hipercard   :  R$ 0,00  
Credz       :  R$ 0,00
```

as the total should be `0,09`.

Comment: There's only one problem...it's still not summing. When i run, the line `TOTAL CARD VALUES CHECKED: R$ 0,00` is always it. It isn't still summing the value of the cards.

Comment: The output I get matches exact as your wanted output in your question. Input is as shown in the answer named `futuroscielotan.txt` which outputs to `Futuros Cielo Tan.txt`. The total line is `TOTAL CARD VALUES CHECKED: R$ 21.689,12`. Ensure you are using similar input else `tokens` and `if`s in `for` loop may need to be changed.

Comment: Not the same that I tested. Try the last example input. The code needs to handle variations in currency.